# How to use a pointer to use the members of a structure inside a nested structure?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, pointer-to-member

Consider the following piece of code:

```cpp
typedef struct
{
    int out;
    struct
    {
        int in1;
        struct
        {
            int in_int2;
            char in_char2;
        } inner2[3];
    } inner1[2];
} outer;

outer o1;
```

How do I use a pointer to point to inner structures, say `o1.inner[0].inner[1]` and assign the values to the same?

i.e. (pseudo code provided for explanation. Exact syntax is being asked:

```cpp
pointer *my_p = o1.inner[0].inner[1];
my_p->in_int2 = 2;
```

Comment: `o1.inner[0].inner[1];` won’t work since there are no members called `inner` inside your struct. The members are named `inner1` and `inner2`.

Answer (score 1):

All of your inner structures are anonymous, so there's no way to reference them.  You need to give each struct a name:

```
typedef struct
{
int out ;
   struct inner1
   {
      int in1;
      struct inner2
      {
          int in_int2;
          char in_char2;
      }inner2[3];
   }inner1[2];
}outer;
```

Then you can create a pointer to the correct type:

```
struct inner2 *my_p = &o1.inner1[0].inner2[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The only options in pure c you would have are:

##### 1. Give the inner structs a name

That way you can reference the concrete type of the inner struct to declare the pointer:

```c
typedef struct
{
    int out;
    struct inner1
    {
        int in1;
        struct inner2
        {
            int in_int2;
            char in_char2;
        } inner2[3];
    } inner1[2];
} outer;

// Usage:
int main() {
    outer o1;
    struct inner2 *ptr = &o1.inner1[1].inner2[2];
    // ...
}
```

##### 2. Define a second equivalent struct as the pointer type

By defining a struct with the exact same members you can cast the pointer to that known struct.
This might be an option in case you can't modify the definition of `outer`.

```c
typedef struct
{
    int out;
    struct
    {
        int in1;
        struct
        {
            int in_int2;
            char in_char2;
        } inner2[3];
    } inner1[2];
} outer;

// Usage:
int main() {
    outer o1;

    struct inner_type { int in_int2; char in_char2; };
    struct inner_type* ptr = (struct inner_type*)&o1.inner1[1].inner2[2];

    // ...
}
```

##### 3. Use pointers directly to the named members

You could also just use pointers to `in_int2` / `in_char2`, that way you don't have to deal with the unnamed structs:

```c
typedef struct
{
    int out;
    struct
    {
        int in1;
        struct
        {
            int in_int2;
            char in_char2;
        } inner2[3];
    } inner1[2];
} outer;

int main() {
    outer o1;

    int* ptr_in_int2 = &o1.inner1[1].inner2[2].in_int2;
    char* ptr_in_char2 =  &o1.inner1[1].inner2[2].in_char2;

    // ...
}
```

---

##### 4. non-standard `typeof()`

If you can use compiler extensions, both gcc and clang provide `typeof()`, which allows you to get the type of an arbitrary expression.

You can use this to create a pointer to the unnamed struct, e.g.:

```c
typedef struct
{
    int out;
    struct
    {
        int in1;
        struct
        {
            int in_int2;
            char in_char2;
        } inner2[3];
    } inner1[2];
} outer;

int main() {
    outer o1;
    typeof(o1.inner1[0].inner2[0])* ptr = &o1.inner1[1].inner2[2];
    // ...
}
```